# Server response Timeout function in parse.com android

Tags: android, parse-platform, timeout, session-timeout

I am working on parse.com android application. Like in normal http request if we don't get the response from the server in a certain time then it will show time out functionality. For example my following code will works for http request time out:

```
            HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);         
            connection.setReadTimeout(3*1000);
```

Now i want the same functionality in parse.com, if i can't get the response from the parse server because of any reason like internet connectivity issue, then it will gives me timeout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Parse.com SDK does not have such functionality which you have described at your question.

But you can do some trick, for example, at `ParseQuery` exists method [cancel()](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#cancel()). So if you want timeout less then standard one, you can run query in background and and wait until or query callback will delivery result of it, or your implementation of timeout  will cancel query running.

Update:

```
public class TimeoutQuery<T extends ParseObject> {
    private ParseQuery<T> mQuery;
    private final long mTimeout;
    private FindCallback<T> mCallback;
    private final Object mLock = new Object();
    private final Thread mThread;


    public TimeoutQuery(ParseQuery<T> query, long timeout) {
        mQuery = query;
        mTimeout = timeout;
        mThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isInterrupted()) return;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(mTimeout);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
                cancelQuery();
            }
        };
    }

    private void cancelQuery() {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (null == mQuery) return; // it's already canceled
            mQuery.cancel();
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mCallback.done(Collections.<T>emptyList(), new ParseException(ParseException.TIMEOUT, ""));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void findInBackground(final FindCallback<T> callback) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mCallback = callback;
            mQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<T>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<T> ts, ParseException e) {
                    synchronized (mLock) {
                        mThread.interrupt();
                        mQuery = null;
                        mCallback.done(ts, e);
                    }
                }
            });
            mThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Test");
 new TimeoutQuery<>(query, 1000).findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    ...
    });
```